expo install with init teamplate
Error downloading and extracting template package: Error: Could not parse JSON returned from "npm pack expo-template-blank --dry-run"
I intend to create a project with exfo using a template, either from blank or template typescript

this solution iam upgrate node and use expo init project_name

When you encounter an error while trying to initialize an Expo project with a template, it typically points to issues with the npm package fetching process. Here are the steps to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:
Step-by-Step Guide:

Check Node.js and npm Versions:
Ensure that you have the latest stable versions of Node.js and npm installed.
node -v
npm -v

You can update Node.js and npm if needed.

Clear npm Cache:
Sometimes, cached files can cause issues. Clearing the npm cache can help.
npm cache clean --force


Update npm:
Ensure that npm is up to date.
npm install -g npm


Install expo-cli:
Make sure you have the latest version of expo-cli installed.
npm install -g expo-cli


Initialize the Expo Project:
Try creating a new project again. Use the following commands depending on the template you want:
For a blank template:
expo init MyNewProject

For a TypeScript template:
expo init MyNewProject --template expo-template-blank-typescript


Check npm Registry:
Ensure that the npm registry is set correctly and that you are not behind a proxy that might be blocking access.
npm config get registry

The default should be https://registry.npmjs.org/. If it’s different, set it back to default:
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/


Manual Installation:
If the above steps do not work, you can try to install the template manually and then create the project:
npm pack expo-template-blank
tar -xzf expo-template-blank-*.tgz

Then move the contents of the extracted directory to your project directory.


Example of Creating a Project with the Template

Creating a Project Directory:
mkdir MyNewProject
cd MyNewProject


Initialize with expo-cli:
expo init --template expo-template-blank


Alternative: Clone the Template Repository Directly:
If all else fails, you can directly clone the template repository from GitHub and set it up manually.
git clone https://github.com/expo/expo-template-blank MyNewProject
cd MyNewProject
npm install



Additional Tips:

Network Issues: Ensure your internet connection is stable.
Permissions: Run the terminal or command prompt as an administrator.
Expo Diagnostics: If issues persist, you can use expo diagnostics to get more information about your environment, which may help in troubleshooting further.

Following these steps should help you resolve the issue and get your Expo project initialized successfully.

If you want to initialise your project with a template typescript you should go with the:
npx create-expo-app <project_name> --template expo-template-blank-typescript

Hope it helps
